# deploying my contract on testnet using geth and truffle without mist/metamask

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle-migration

It is showing error on migrating to the testnetwork-

> $ truffle migrate --network ourTestNet

```
Compiling ./contracts/Wrestling.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/home/mayank/Desktop/Truffle/trial/contracts/Wrestling.sol:35:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        WrestlingStartsEvent(wrestler1,wrestler2);
        ^---------------------------------------^
,/home/mayank/Desktop/Truffle/trial/contracts/Wrestling.sol:68:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        EndOfRoundEvent(wrestler1Deposit,wrestler2Deposit);
        ^------------------------------------------------^
,/home/mayank/Desktop/Truffle/trial/contracts/Wrestling.sol:75:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        EndOfWrestlingEvent(theWinner,gains);
        ^----------------------------------^

Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'ourTestNet'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: unknown account
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:225:1
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:114:19)
```

Migration.sol-

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function Migrations() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

truffle.js-

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
    networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ourTestNet: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7000,
      network_id: "*" 
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please do update the code with the truffle.js info

Comment: i have updated those files.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the default `Migrations.sol` file, which is required by truffle to store the current migration step. Usually, this file is created by `truffle init`, but you can also download it directly from the template project at GitHub -> https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-init-bare/blob/master/contracts/Migrations.sol

Comment: i am not missing that i have that included and the first account that is coinbase is unlocked too

Comment: Then try to delete your build subdirectory, call ``truffle compile`` and call migrate again.